# Offset function returns #VALUE! with small dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have some data in excel and want to access certain rows with the offset function, however the function returns `#VALUE!` for my small dataset.

Using this, `OFFSET(A2;0;0;COUNTA(A2:A99999);1)` I get `#VALUE!`. When changing the formula to `OFFSET(A2;0;0;100;1)` I get a value.

[image]

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What is the full formula? You seem to have omitted a wrapping function like SUM or something similar.

Comment: @Jeeped Thx for your answer! However, this is my formula. I am using this part in a very complex vba script and it returns me `#VALUE`

Comment: @mrquad [Offset function documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592). It returns a range, as MissPalmer answered. You need to use the range somehow. Btw, if you put either of your formulas in the row with data, you can see it will return the data from that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `=OFFSET(A2;0;0;COUNTA(A2:A99999);1)` is your full formula you are getting a result with a hard-coded number due to **Inferred Position** (I hope that's the right term). This means that when you are referencing a range but are not processing the full range the operative cell is the one relative to the current position.

If you put `=$A$2:$A$11` in D2 and fill down you will get processive results according to your row position that match column A. Keep filling down and you will get the `#VALUE!` error when you go past row 11.

This is why `=OFFSET(A2; 0; 0; 100; 1)` returns a zero and  `=OFFSET(A2; 0; 0; COUNTA(A2:A99999); 1)` returns a `#VALUE!` error. The first formula is the same as saying `=$A$2:$A$101` and it is returning zero because you put the formula in a cell that was above row 101 (referencing a blank cell in column A that returned a value of *0*). The second (with the [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a)) is like saying `=$A$2:$A$11` and you are putting it into a cell in row 13 (below row 11).

**Addndum:**

On a related note, these variations of the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) are non-volatile and more functional than the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) while providing a cell range reference identical to what you were achieving with OFFSET and the [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a).

```
'for text in a column
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH("zzz", $A:$A))

'for numbers in a column
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1e99, $A:$A))

'for unknown in a column
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A, IFERROR(MATCH(1e99, $A:$A), MATCH("zzz", $A:$A)))

'for combined in a column
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MAX(MATCH(1e99, $A:$A), MATCH("zzz", $A:$A)))

'I don't like COUNTA but it works as long as there are no blanks
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A, COUNTA($A:$A))
```

There are many variations on this method. Perhaps you can use one of the above for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`OFFSET(A2;0;0;(range > 1);1)` will return an array rather than the value of a single cell. This only makes sense if you put sum or some other aggregate function around it. (What are you trying to achieve with the formula?)

e.g.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A2;0;0;COUNTA(A2:A99999);1))
```